# On Rails, editing collection of objects with nested resources on the go

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a backend for content curation.

There's a collection of objects with nested associations, currently is only displaying them. Not scoped on any `form_for` for this yet.

I would like to show the editable fields as input and be able to edit them and update on the go (no need for clicking on a save button or reload the page).

I'm a little lost in how to do such implementation on Rails. Is there a gem to simplify this or any idea where should I look at to begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [best in place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem.

https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place